# Loadrunner truclient licensing

Tags: licensing, loadrunner, truclient

The company I work for has Loadrunner and I think about 400 vusers licence.
I also know that they have TruClient in the VUGen. But do they need to by additional TruClient licenses or does the current ammount of 400 also include TruClient VUsers to use from the controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the LoadRunner Help documentation.

"Note: In order to run the various protocols, you must have either a global license or licenses for the desired protocols. For more information, select Configuration > LoadRunner License in the LoadRunner Launcher (Start > Programs > LoadRunner > LoadRunner)."

I would take that to mean you need licenses specifically for the TruClient protocol as well, unless the 400 that you have are global. I'm no Performance Center admin mind you, I just hack out a script or two every once in awhile.

Comment: I will check tomorrow if they have global or per-protocol licenses. If I understand you correctly given they have global; using some or all of the 400 to run TruClient VUsers from the controllers should not be a problem. However if they have per protocol and not TruClient licenses they must buy seperate licenses for TruClient?

Comment: That's my understanding yes. Good luck.